# Is it possible to add 1fr padding to a grid element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to build this layout using a CSS grid.

[image]

The actual grid and its elements work fine using this simple markup and CSS:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  column-gap: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.grid__col { }

.grid__col.grid__col--a {
  grid-column: 1/span 6;
  background: navy;
}

.grid__col.grid__col--b {
  grid-column: 7/span 4;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__col grid__col--a">A</div>
  <div class="grid__col grid__col--b">B</div>
</div>
```

But there's one issue. As you can see in the screenshot, the content inside the blue element should have a padding that's excatly `1fr` (or even `2fr` with column gap etc).

I know that there's `subgrid` coming, but only Firefox 71 supports it at the moment. I also tried to add another box with the background color that overlap with the actual content, like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  column-gap: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.grid__col {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.grid__col.grid__col--c {
  grid-column: 1/span 6;
  background: navy;
}

.grid__col.grid__col--a {
  grid-column: 2/span 4;
}

.grid__col.grid__col--b {
  grid-column: 7/span 4;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__col grid__col--c"></div>
    <div class="grid__col grid__col--a">A</div>
    <div class="grid__col grid__col--b">B</div>
  </div>
```

The problem is, that this box is always as high as the grid row and not like the actual content. This might be a problem, when the right container is higher than the left one.

Is there a way to accomplish this using CSS grid?

Comment: Why not using `%` value for padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `calc()` and you can get the exact value of `1fr`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  column-gap: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.grid__col { }

.grid__col.grid__col--a {
  grid-column: span 6;
  padding:0 calc((100% - 5*40px)/6);   /* 100% = 6fr + 5 gaps ==> 1fr = (100% - 5 gaps)/6 */
  background: navy;
}

.grid__col.grid__col--b {
  grid-column: span 4;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__col grid__col--a">A</div>
  <div class="grid__col grid__col--b">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you feedback. I tried this already (when replicating the grid using flexbox in another attempt). It seems to be the only solution. While this works, it involves some complex `calc()` calls, which are not pixel perfect on some resolutions in Webkit browsers. Also you need to create lots of classes, if you want to make it more generic. Too bad `subgrid` is not there yet. ;)